# detecting parse errors during parsing

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How can I detect that the errors that are generated by the parser programmatically? For instance given this grammar:

```
s  : 'hello' ;
```

and this program with input: `"foo bar"`

```
ParseTree tree = parser.s();
```

the parser would print out `"line 1:0 mismatched input 'foo' expecting 'hello'"`. Is there a way to detect parse failure programmatically? It doesn't seem to throw exception of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the ANTLRErrorListener interface and add it to the parser:

```
    Parser#addErrorListener(ANTLRErrorListener);
```

Typically, want to first remove the default console-ouput listener:

```
    Parser#removeErrorListeners()
```